# Is there a way to level up your pokemon easily without leaving it in the Day Care Centre?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Any ways to level up pokemons without putting them into day care centre?

Comment: How do you define 'easily'?

Answer (score 7):

One of the easiest ways to grind experience:

Requirements for maximum experience:

- Lucky Egg (50% boost in Exp)
- Traded Pokemon (i.e. one you got via trade; these Pokemon get 50% more experience than usual)
- Experience O Power (20%, 50% and 100% boost in Exp for each level from 1 to 3)
- At least 3 hearts in Pokemon Amie (20% boost in Exp)
- Exp Share (if low levelled Pokemon)

Go to Lumiose City's restaurant Le Wow (3 stars) and do the Triple Battles (or Rotation for lower levelled Pokemon) option. You will need 90,000 - 100,000 poke to enter (depending on your Lumiose style points)

[image]

<sub>Original map [here](http://www.hailstormgaming.net/topic/925-pokemon-x-and-y-lumios-city-map/) by potato</sub>

It's actually shorter from the Northern Boulevard PokeCentre.

Make sure to activate your O-Power for Experience before dining (and you can activate the O-Power for money as well, since you'll get plenty too!) which will remain active until your whole meal is over.

You get raw Exp of 35,315 for the whole meal for all Pokemon taking part in the battle directly (and of course half if they obtained Exp through Exp Share alone). If you apply every requirement I listed initially, that makes 113,000 Exp total.

Comment: If your team's levels aren't much higher than the restaurant's team, you may consider a Water Absorb team. This provides you both damage and healing. For instance, I went with a Quagsire, Lapras and Vaporeon (in this order). Lapras had Surf, which healed both Quagsire and Vaporeon, and hit the whole opposing team. Also, consider holding Amulet Coin. The boosted prize money will make up for the entry fee.

Answer (score 3):

First, Get 500,000 dollars by using the restaurants.

1. Get 6 lucky eggs (Chansey holds them in the friend safari)
2. Get 3 hearts in Poke Amie (optional)
3. Use Exp O-power during these next battles
4. Set your 3ds time to 0:00 and buy the Black writ of challenge in the Battle Chateu
5. Get a Marchioness or duchess rank depends on gender
6. Wait during the day until you see those girls in the dresses
7. Battle them because they have Audinos
8. When the day is about to end set your 3ds clock to 0:00 again that way you don't have to pay for the writ again tomorrow
9. Repeat

Comment: Note that setting the time on your 3ds cancels all active Writs. So point 8 is wrong, you *will* have to pay again. Also, using the Silver Writ of Invitation additionally will make more opponents appear. Usually, the income from those battles easily covers the cost of the writs.

Answer (score 2):

One way of getting the experience to all of you pokémon is through using the "Exp Share" which will grant experience to all Pokémon that you have with you.

From what I've found it's: the lead Pokemon does get 100% experience, and everybody else in you're party get's half of that amount.

Quote:

> For those who haven't gotten X/Y yet, the new EXP SHARE item differs
>   from previous incarnations in the following ways:
>
> 1. It's received extremely early in the game.
> 2. It distributes experience to your entire party, rather than just the one who held it.
> 3. It's not actually a held item anymore, therefore allowing the party members to hold actually useful items.
>
> Basically, the archaic practice of having to constantly swap out
>   pokemon to ensure that they're all getting experience has been
>   massively mitigated. You can literally not use any pokemon except your
>   starter and the rest of your party will not be the same level as that
>   starter, but will at least not be in any danger of falling massively
>   behind.
>
> What I'm saying is that this is the greatest thing to happen ever.

You get it in **Santalune City** after beating the first gym leader.

Answer (score 0):

Using the exp. share will give all your pokemon experience, but for more exp., put the pokemon you are leveling up in the top left part of your party. After entering battle, switch out to one of your stronger pokemon. There are lots of other ways to make your pokemon gain levels, but I find these easiest, and you can use these strategies anywhere.

Comment: epic name, epic gamer

Answer (score 0):

Probably on Route 21 or Route 20, Because with Pokémon with a level that high you need to train there instead of anywhere else. All the Pokémon on those Routes are level 48,49 or 50.
Also you can train on Victory Road. There are high-level Pokémon there to from level 48 to level 51 or 52. The final place that you can train at is The Pokémon League, every person there  has Pokémon that are levels 64 or 63.