# Leveling Pokemon using the Lumiose Tower infinite loop path

Tags: pokemon-x-y

So there is this cheat thing where you leave your Pokemon in the daycare and go to the Lumiose Tower and do the infinite loop thing, but how long does it take to get from level 1 to level 100?

Answer (score 10):

First we need to measure exactly how many steps each loop is. There is [another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/273175/30115) that answers that, but I performed a different test: I took a Noctowl I had and noted down its current Exp before depositing it (128907), I then counted the steps out of the daycare (7) flew to Lumiose and counted the steps to the loop (10) performed one loop, flew back to Camphrier and counted the steps back to the daycare desk (113), and my Noctowl now had 129,216 Exp, minus distance between the daycare and the loop (*130 steps*), the figure I get for the loop is **179 Steps**

Next we need to know how long each loop around the tower takes. Doing some quick tests with a stopwatch app on my phone, it takes roughly **12.35 seconds** per lap around Lumiose Tower (while riding the bike).

Finally we need to know how much Exp will get a Pokemon to 100. This is *slightly* more complicated than you might think; you see - [not all Pokemon require the same amount of experience to reach lvl 100](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Experience#Relation_to_level). There are 6 different groups of experience growth that each require different amounts of total Exp to reach lvl 100:

1. [Erratic](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Category:Pok%C3%A9mon_in_the_Erratic_experience_group): 600,000 Exp
2. [Fast](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Category:Pok%C3%A9mon_in_the_Fast_experience_group): 800,000 Exp
3. [Medium Fast](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Category:Pok%C3%A9mon_in_the_Medium_Fast_experience_group): 1,000,000 Exp
4. [Medium Slow](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Category:Pok%C3%A9mon_in_the_Medium_Slow_experience_group): 1,059,860 Exp
5. [Slow](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Category:Pok%C3%A9mon_in_the_Slow_experience_group): 1,250,000 Exp
6. [Fluctuating](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Category:Pok%C3%A9mon_in_the_Fluctuating_experience_group): 1,640,000 Exp

Most sites like Serebii or Bulbapedia should tell you which experience category each Pokemon falls under.[image]

---

Knowing those numbers, we just need to plug them into the following formula:

```
Time_to_lvl_100 = ( [Exp] - [Steps to/from loop] ) / [steps per loop] * [Time per loop]
```

or  more simply: `Time_to_lvl_100=(EXP-130)/179*12.35` This will ultimately give us the total number of seconds, but I'll skip that and break it down into hours/minutes/seconds for each Exp category:

- Erratic: 3,351.23 rounds, or **11 hours, 29 minutes, 48 seconds**
- Fast: 4,468.55 rounds, or **15 hours, 19 minutes, 47 seconds**
- Medium Fast: 5,585.87 rounds, or **19 hours, 9 minutes, 45 seconds**
- Medium Slow: 5,920.28 rounds, or **20 hours, 18 minutes, 35 seconds**
- Slow: 6,982.51 rounds, or **23 hours, 57 minutes, 14 seconds**
- Fluctuating: 9,161.28 rounds, or **31 hours, 25 minutes, 42 seconds**

(Note: these times may vary depending on the accuracy of my measuring of the steps and time per loop)

---

If you insist on leveling Pokemon this way, since you can level two at a time, I suggest trying to pair up Pokemon that share an experience group so that they level at the same rate and one isn't sitting in there finished while the other still has hours to go.

Also - if you want the Pokemon to evolve and it **requires** a level-up to do so (any evolution NOT triggered by using an evolution stone or by trading), make sure you take it out and level it up once or twice (while meeting any other requirements) either through battle or with a rare-candy ***before*** it hits lvl 100, or it will be *stuck* un-evolved. Pokemon in the daycare will learn moves as they level up, but they will *not* evolve. If you need to know the time to 100 on a Pokemon that is not a 0-Exp lvl 1, it is the same formula, but the value for `EXP` is the total Exp for lvl100 minus it's current Exp.

If you are not just looking for a way to level up Pokemon without interacting much (while asleep / at work or school); unless you are early in the game and haven't fully unlocked them, I highly suggest using the restaurants or Battle Chateau to level Pokemon [*far* more efficiently](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/149311/30115).

Comment: I added important information regarding evolution; as pokemon left in the daycare *do not evolve*, if you aren't careful you may end up with a lvl100 Pokemon **unable** to evolve and have wasted many hours. I cannot stress this enough, so I'm also leaving this as a comment.

Comment: If I use the other question's *219 steps* figure (assuming the time per loop remains the same) the times work out to around [9h34m], [12h32m], [15h40m], [16h37m], [19s35m], and [25h42m] respectively.

Comment: The resulting number of steps of each loop is affected by the position of the player (radius from the tower), we probably used a different circumference or my sample was too small.